# Split Excel Sheet from one Excel file to Multiple Excel file

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Splitbook()
MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
sht.Copy
ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
Filename:=MyPath & "\" & sht.Name & ".xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True
Next sht
End Sub
```

It is giving an error

> Runtime error 1004
>   Copy method of worksheet class failed

How can i remove this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test code using objects to handle the copy properly:

```
Sub Splitbook()
Dim MyPath As String
Dim ShT As Worksheet
Dim NewWB As Workbook
Dim NewSHT As Worksheet
    MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    For Each ShT In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        ShT.Copy
        Set NewWB = ActiveWorkbook
        With NewWB
            With .Sheets(1)
                With .Cells
                .Copy
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
                End With '.Cells
            End With '.Sheets(1)
            .SaveAs FileName:=MyPath & "\" & ShT.Name & ".xlsx"
            .Close savechanges:=True
        End With 'NewWB
    Next ShT
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable input but after crating the excel of first sheet it is again throwing error Method 'copy' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Comment: @ShivaGupta : I don't have any issue on my side, so the problem is probably coming from your sheet. What is the name of the sheet it errors on?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Splitbook()
MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
sht.usedrange.copy
set wb= workbooks.add
wb.sheets(1).Paste
application.cutcopymode=false
wb.saveas(filename:=MyPath & "_" & sht.Name & ".xlsx",xlopenXMLworkbook)
wb.close
Next sht
End Sub
```

try this subroutine this might work. I havent tested the code. Please forgive me if there are any bugs.